# How to restart a systemd service without a tty?

Tags: systemd, gitlab

Maybe I'm looking at this the wrong way, but I'm trying to setup my gitlab ci to be able to autodeploy code on push.  Seems like a fairly simple process, and I've successfully gotten most of it working.  I may be completely misunderstanding how systemd works, also, as I'm fairly new to it.

I have a node application that I'm pushing to gitlab, and that will successfully kick off deploy logic, but the last step I'm doing is to restart the application in order to make sure I'm actually pulling in all the code changes (as I understand it, changes to modules would not happen w/o restarting the service, as the npm cache keeps modules in memory once required).

My gitlab ci yaml file looks like this:

```
stages:
  - deploy

deploy-prod:
  stage: deploy
  variables:
    BRANCH_REF: master
  script:
    - git fetch
    - git checkout $BRANCH_REF
    - git pull origin $BRANCH_REF
    - npm install
    - rm -rf /opt/my-app/www
    - ln -s $CI_PROJECT_DIR /opt/my-app/www
    - sh /home/gitlab-runner/restart.sh
  tags:
    - production
```

I probably don't need the indirection of the symlink, but that doesn't matter for this question.  I made that `restart.sh` file because I was getting the error `sudo: sorry, you must have a tty to run sudo`, and I thought I could wrap it in a shell file. But that didn't change things.

So, how do I let my gitlab-runner user restart the service when it updates the files?

My systemd config looks like this:

```
[Unit]
After=mongod.service

[Service]
ExecStart=/usr/bin/node /opt/my-app/www/server
Restart=always
StandardOutput=syslog
StandardError=syslog
SyslogIdentifier=my-app
User=my-app
Group=my-app
Environment=NODE_ENV=production
```

And my visudo is setup to allow the git-runner user to run `systemctl restart my-app.service` without a password, and I've tested that successfully by su'ing to gitlab-runner and running the command without error but again the error indicates I should not even be allowed to use the keyword `sudo` at all.  Here's the relevant sudoers entry:

`gitlab-runner   ALL=(ALL)   NOPASSWD: /bin/systemctl restart my-app`

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

I do something much like this. You *don't* need a TTY in this case, but you *do* need to for the path you are calling with sudo to exactly what match what's in your `sudoers` file. In you case, that means you need to make sure your restart script script does:

```
 sudo /bin/systemctl restart my-app
```

And NOT

```
 sudo systemctl restart my-app
```

You can easily test that your `sudo` setup is working right becoming root and using `su -l gitlab-runner` to become that user.  Finally, manually run your `restart.sh` script. You should *not* be prompted for a password (which is the part that's attempting to use the TTY).

Comment: So, my restart.sh was already setup as you suggest, but my sudoers didn't match it.  Correcting that did not correct the error, however, I'm still getting the error in the gitlab-ci pipeline.  It's worth pointing out that I did test it when logged in as gitlab-runner and it worked fine; but it does not work when the ci pipeline is calling it.

Answer (score 2):

Ok, so after digging around some more, it turns out that there was the entry in my sudoers file:

```
Defaults requiretty
```

Commenting that out fixes the problem, and from some [research](https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1020147) it looks like there's no real security benefit from keeping it there.